# How to click the cell in the table WITHOUT making its color blue (in HTML/CSS)?

Tags: html, css

[Screenshot: It looks so ugly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffPw3.png)

Is there any way to do this?
I implement the whole [bootstrap.css](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/), and I don't have any other CSS style besides this:
(I also add style="background: antiquewhite" in  tag)

```
table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border-spacing: 0;
        table-layout: fixed;
        margin: 3px 0; 
        text-align:center;
        cursor: default; 
    }
```

Source code for the table are simple:

```
<table width="100%" id="a">
    <tr>
        <td><h2>a</h2></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Besides, I use popover in my website,

```
<td data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-html="true" data-content="<table width='100px'>
<tr>
<td><a href='http://www.google.com' target='_blank'>google</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><a href='http://www.google.com' target='_blank'>google</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
"><h4>something</h4></td>
```

I don't know whether this still works without making the cell blue

Comment: Do you have code? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: In the inspector find the element and set to ":active" state. Check to see what styles are applied... `:active { outline: none }` may fix, but without some source code it's hard to say.

Comment: I'm sorry. I have provided the source code here. I thought this would be the most basic example so I didn't put it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its clearly a css rule set.

something like `tr:active`, but please provide the CSS

try use this, replace yellow with the hex value of the normal table color:

```
td:active,
tr td:active,
td:hover,
tr td:hover {
    background-color: antiquewhite!important;
}
```

`:active` is the state of an element after its getting clicked (active),
`!important` tells css to overwrite all other rules without `!important`.

Comment: I'm a beginner in HTML/CSS, so I implement the whole bootstrap.css stylesheet.

Comment: But this isn't Bootstraps styling! Can you tell me the 'background-color' it has by default (this yellow-ish color)?

Comment: I have added my <style> ... </style>. I'm sorry for inconvenience!

Comment: I've edited my answer, it should work for you if not, you have set an 'important' anywhere else

Answer (score 0):

You should open developer tools in your browser and select the offending cell. It will show you all the css associated with the selection and tell you which line in which CSS file it is from.